# Visual Studio - String Interpolation Shortcut (Without Install VS Extensions)

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, string-interpolation

I started to write a message, but didn't know if I need to interpolate it. So, I'm in the middle of the message and want to put a `$` to interpolate my string.

It would be helpful if some shortcut exists for it.

Like this:

```
Log("Something happen here, at... (Oh God, I will need interpolate it..) {DateTime.Now}...");
```

Is there one?

Comment: If one does not exist, you can create one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/identifying-and-customizing-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017

But just an FYI, it is in the format $"some value is {somevalue}"

Comment: No, this does not exist currently.

Comment: @ViniciusGonçalves - exactly! :[

Answer (score 3):

With Resharper you can press `alt+enter` the first suggestion is "to string interpolation".

[image: to string interpolation]

Comment: I think it is Resharper, not Visual Studio :/

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following command to Visual Commander and assign a shortcut to it:
[Add the string interpolation character $ to the beginning of the current string](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/commands.html#AddInterpolation).

Comment: Nice alternative @Sergey Vlasov! Tks

Comment: I just gave this a try in VS2017 and am getting this error: `(32,16): error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.IComponentModel.GetService<T>()' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.` 
 Changing the last line to return `componentModel.GetService<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService>();` fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure when this was added, but in Visual Studio 2019, Version 16.9.4 at least, you  can use Quick Actions to do exactly this.

The trick is that you have to have at least one left or right bracket character in the string. The moment you type one of those characters, it gives the Quick Actions option to "Convert to interpolated string".

My only hang-up is it seems to be duplicating the brackets you already typed in, but with some <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> it's quick to remove them. A lot easier than switching to a mouse or going all the way back to the beginning of the string declaration, IMO.

[image: String Interpolation Quick Action]

Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

you can use it in below case with `$`:

```
Log($"Something happen here, at... (Oh God, I will need interpolate it..) {DateTime.Now}...");
```

before use it, you need install `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` package
for more information: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/03/23/how-to-enable-c-7-in-visual-studio-2017/

Comment: What about the shortcut?

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question, which is about a shortcut; furthermore, string interpolation is a C# 6 feature, so there is no package installation necessary on VS2015 or newer.

Answer (score -2):

Actually i was also searching for this for so much of time. Then i realised that **we have that symbol just before 1 key in the keyboard**. [for better understanding click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP1a9.jpg)

Comment: I'm not following. How does this symbol inject a `$` at the beginning of a string in order to permit string interpolation?